# netpoll APIの受信について

Tags: linux

linux kernel 3.14まではnetpoll APIの

```
struct netpoll
```

の.rx_hookメンバーに
受信時の関数を設定することで受信が行えました。

3.15からはrx_hookメンバーが無くなっています。

受信の仕組みが変わったのか、であればその方法をお教えください。
あるいは、netpoll APIは受信のサポートをやめてしまったのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下を見る限り、kernel code から削除されてしまった様です。

[netpoll: Remove dead packet receive code (CONFIG_NETPOLL_TRAP)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=9c62a68d13119a1ca9718381d97b0cb415ff4e9d)

コミットログの最後に以下の文章があります。

> Given that the netpoll packet receive code is buggy, there are no out of tree users that will be merged soon, and the code has not been used for in tree for a decade let's just remove it. **Reverting this commit can server as a starting point for anyone who wants to resurrect netpoll packet reception support**.